# Tree Simple Data Manipulation

Tags: c++, tree, octree

We've been tasked to create an Octree that has blue and white voxels. However, I've only been able to get the correct answers for Inputs with Level 1 and Level 2.

Details:

1. p - denotes that the large voxel still needs to be divided into  octants

   - b - voxel is blue
   - w - voxel is white
2. Assume that voxels that were not assigned any color are white
3. Input: N denotes how many pairs are to be added to each other

Correct Output:

```
4096
3072
2048
1184
```

Input:

```
4
b
w
pbbbbwwww
pbwbwbwbw
pbpbbwwwwbbwwwwpbbwwwwbbb
ppbbwwwwbbbwwwwbpbbwwwwbb
pppbwwwwwbwwwwwwbwwwwwwbw
pwpwpwbwwwwwbwwwwwbwwwwwb
```

Octree:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue> 
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 

int N,lvl;
string s1,s2;
int index_a = 0;
int index_b = 0;
int VCount();

struct Node 
{ 
    char data;
    vector<Node *>child; 
}; 

Node *newNode(char data) 
{ 
    Node *temp = new Node; 
    temp->data = data;
    return temp; 
} 

Node *root;
int Voxels(vector<Node *> _root, int level);


int main() 
{ 
    cin>>N;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        root = newNode('w');
        cin>>s1;
        cin>>s2;
            lvl = 1;
            for(int j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++){
                if(s1[j] == 'p')
                    lvl++;
            }
        cout<<VCount();
        cout<<'\n';
        index_a = 0;
        index_b = 0;
        lvl = 0;
    }     
return 0;   
}  

int VCount(){

    int _vox = 0;

        for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++)                                                                      //  Level 1
            (root->child).push_back(newNode('w'));   
                if (lvl == 1)
                return Voxels(root->child,1);

            if (lvl >= 2){
                 for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){                                                             //  Level 2
                    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                        (root->child[k]->child).push_back(newNode('w'));
                    }
                 }
                _vox = Voxels(root->child,2);


            if (lvl >= 3){
                for(int l = 0; l < 8; ++l){
                    for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){                                                         //  Level 3
                        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                            (root->child[l]->child[k]->child).push_back(newNode('w')); 
                        }

                    }
                    _vox += Voxels(root->child[l]->child,3);
                }


                if (lvl == 4){
                    for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++){      
                        for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){                                                     //  Level 4
                            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                                    (root->child[l]->child[k]->child[j]->child).push_back(newNode('w'));   
                            }
                        _vox += Voxels(root->child[l]->child[k]->child,4);
                    }
                  }
                }

            }

        }

    return _vox;  
}

int Voxels(vector<Node *> _root, int level){
int _voxels = 0;
int _ind;
int branch = 0;

        if(s1.size() == 1){
                if(s1[index_a] =='b' || s2[index_b] == 'b')
                    return 4096;
                else
                    return 0;
            }

        index_a++;
        index_b++;
        _ind = index_a;


            if(s1[index_a] != 'p' && s2[index_b] != 'p'){
                for(int i = index_a, j = 0; i < s1.size() && s1[i] != 'p'; i++,j++){
                    if(s1[i] == 'b'){
                        _root[branch]->child[j]->data = 'b';
                        _voxels++;
                    }
                    if(j==7){
                        branch++;
                        j=0;
                    }
                    index_a = i;  
                }
                for(int i = index_b, j = 0; i < s2.size() && s2[i] != 'p'; i++, j++){
                    if(s2[i] == 'b' && s1[_ind] != 'b'){
                        _root[branch]->child[j]->data = 'b';
                        _voxels++;
                    }
                    if(j==7){
                        branch++;
                        j=0;
                    }
                   _ind++;
                }
            }

return (4096/pow(8,level-1))*_voxels;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you read the last four lines of the input. What does the output represent?

Comment: You read them by pair and add them together. B + B = B, B+W = B, W+W = W :)

Comment: If you're talking about the input, if they aren't read, then there's nothing to add. If you're talking about the output, those are numbers -- what do the numbers represent?